# Populate today's date in a field based on item selected in drop down list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, list-form

Apologies in advance, I am extremely new to SharePoint.

Looking for some assistance if I could please? Is there anyway to populate a date field with today's date based on whatever item I select from a drop down?

Example:

Drop Down:

```
Option #1
Option #2
Option #3
```

Date Field:

```
Option #1
Option #2
Option #3
```

IF `Option#1` is selected in Drop Down, THEN enter today's date into Date Field  `Option#1` ELSE

IF `Option #2` is selected in Drop Down, THEN enter today's date into Date Field  `Option#2` etc.

Any guidance would be great, thank you - Essentially, we have a self developed workflow at work (not created as a true workflow, it is just a LIST interfaced with an Infopath form).

Thanks you, any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you Emily - I am using SharePoint Online and I do not have any experience with workflows at this stage. Is this achievable through calculated field formulas? Apologies again, as per above I am very new to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a SharePoint 2010 workflow associated with the list. Start option set as "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed".
[image]